# Eloquent Model's relations not working; Not even a query

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I'm having a User and a Role model in a child-parent relationship as the code below shows. What happens is that I can access the child through the parent, but not vice versa. Accessing the child's role ($user->role) only gives me the ID. The role column has a foreign key on the roles table, but the opposite is not working.
Basically,
$role contains all the users
$user->role does not show the user's role, only his id

Laravel-Debugbar additionally shows that user does not perform an extra query, while role does.

users table

`id
name
email
password
remember_token
client
role
created_at
updated_at`

roles table

`id
name
display_name
description
created_at
updated_at`

User Model

```
namespace App;
use Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Laratrust\Traits\LaratrustUserTrait;
use App\Client;
use App\Role;
use App\Permission;

class User extends Authenticatable
{
    use LaratrustUserTrait;
    use Notifiable;

    protected $fillable = [
        'name', 'email', 'password','role',
    ];
    public function client(){
        return $this->hasOne('App\Client', 'client');
    }
    public function role(){
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Role')->withDefault();
    }
}
```

Role Model

```
namespace App;

use Laratrust\Models\LaratrustRole;
use App\Permission;
use App\User;

class Role extends LaratrustRole
{
            protected $fillable = [
        'name', 'display_name', 'description',
    ];
        public function GetHasPermission($perm){
            return DB::table('permission_role')->where('role', $this->id)
                    ->where('permission',$perm)->first()->value('type');
        }
        public function users(){
            return $this->hasMany('App\User','role', 'id');
        }
        public function permissions(){
            return $this->hasMany('App\Permission');
        }
        public function getName(){
            return $this->name;
        }
}
```

EDIT: It should be noted that I'm using Laratrust.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since you're not following [Laravel naming conventions](https://github.com/alexeymezenin/laravel-best-practices#follow-laravel-naming-conventions), you need to define foreign key manually. So, change the `role()` relationship to:

```
public function role()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Role', 'role')->withDefault();
}
```

https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent-relationships#one-to-many-inverse

Then use `->role()->first()` instead of `->role`. `->role()` uses relationship directly. `->role` first trying to use a property of an object and if it doesn't exist, it loads related data (an object or a collection). Since User object has role property, Laravel uses it instead of loading related Role object.

Comment: Exactly. Laravel is looking for a role_id instead of role

Comment: Tried that already; Doesn't work even though it's supposed to be correct.

Comment: @Statharas.903 I'm pretty sure the code is correct. If you want help, please tell me what error do you have with this code.

Comment: Pulling the user model in any way does not show the parent (role) at all. Specifically, I'm doing Auth::user()->role and it just returns the ID of the role, same with User::find(1). Role::find(1)->users correctly returns the users with that role.
Obviously, accessing Auth::user()->role->name gives a `Trying to get property of non-object` error

Comment: @Statharas.903 so, you're trying to do `$user->role`. Do `$user->role()->first()` instead or change the relationship name to something different from foreign key.

Comment: That works but I don't get why? When I pull `$role->users`, I get an array of all the users, what exactly does `$user->role()` end up returning?

Comment: @Statharas.903 `->role()` uses relationship directly. `->role` first trying to use a property of an object and if it doesn't exist, it loads related data (an object or a collection). Since  `User` object has `role` property, Laravel uses it instead of loading related `Role` object.

Comment: Post that as an answer to select is as an answer

Comment: @Statharas.903 added to the answer.

Comment: You forgot the part about using ->first() :P
That's what got everything to work.